# How do I represent a tags relationship in neo4j where user needs to be identified

Tags: neo4j, cypher

So here's the problem I have with my data model

I have artists, users and tags

Tags are unique data objects that I am storing in nodes.

Users can tag artists with certain tags

I started with the following relationship

```
(user)-[:tags]->(tag)-[:on]->(artist)
```

OFcourse this fails to identify the user who tagged the artist.

Then I thought of trying the following approach

```
(user)-[:tags]->(artist)->[:with]->(tag)
```

Here, I can identify the artist, but cannot identify what the tag for the artist was.

I am a little lost here. I know I could simply go

```
(user)-[:tags {tagname}]->artist
```

But is there any way of representing tag as an independent entity while still maintaining data associated on both ends

Comment: Are the tags users apply meant to be globally visible to all other users, or is the visibility meant to be personal and for that user's eyes and use only?

Comment: Tags are global meant to be visible to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want an [hypergraph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergraph) with edges connecting more than 2 vertices (the user, the tag, the artist).

However, Neo4j is not an hypergraph implementation, so you'll need to introduce a node representing the "user tag" and connected to the 3 nodes with regular relationships:

```
MATCH (user:User {uuid: {userId}}),
      (tag:Tag {uuid: {tagId}}),
      (artist:Artist {uuid: {artistId}})
CREATE (user)-[:USER_TAGS]->(userTag:UserTag)-[:USES_TAG]->(tag),
       (userTag)-[:TAGS_ARTIST]->(artist)
```

Neo4j is a property graph model. Generally:

> Because hyperedges are multidimensional, hypergraph models are more generalized than property graphs. Yet, the two are isomorphic, so you can always represent a hypergraph as a property graph (albeit with more relationships and nodes) – whereas you can’t do the reverse.

https://neo4j.com/blog/other-graph-database-technologies/

Comment: Thanks, but I was hopinh not to introduce another node. Any idea how it compares  to 
(user)-[:tags {tagId}]->(artist)-[:with]->(tag {tagId}) vis a vis performance

Comment: Also, thanks for telling me about Hypergraphs. I didn't know that before

Comment: Regarding the performance, it depends what you want to do, i.e. your queries.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to break up this up into two discrete pieces: the tags that are applied to the user (assuming a unique constraint on the tag name), and the tagging relationship from the tagger to the taggee. Unsure whether your system only allows use of predefined tags, or if users are allowed to dynamically create them.

Let's assume for the moment that tags are predefined: You have nodes with the :Tag label, and you might use queries on that label to generate lists of tags users can use, or to use for autocompletion of tags as the user types.

So say a user wants to tag an artist with a tag. This will trigger an operation that first tags the artist with the tag, and then creates the :tags relationship between the user and the artist.

```
MATCH (t:Tag {name:tagname}), (a:Artist {id:artistID}), (u:User {id:userID})
MERGE (t)<-[:taggedAs]-(a)
MERGE (user)-[:tags {tagname}]->(artist)
```

The advantage of this approach is that you preserve both pieces of information (that a user has tagged an artist with specific tags, and that the artist is tagged as certain tags) in such a way that it's easy to query both pieces of information: given a user and an artist, we can quickly figure out the :tags relationships between them and get the tags with those names. We can also easily query what tags apply to the artist from all users without the expense of having to iterate through every single :tags relationship from all users.

The downside is that tag removal by a user is a more complex operation, possibly with a race condition: the :tags relationship between the user and artist has to be deleted, then all other :tags relationships from other users to that artist need to be checked to see if that tag still applies to the user, or if we need to remove it. You may need locks on this operation to prevent a race condition. If tag removal by a user is not allowed or is rare, then this could be an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 2):

you can tag artist with the help of tagId to identify

```
(user)-[:tags {tagId}]->(artist)-[:with]->(tag {tagId})
```

Comment: Is that the correct approach? neo4j tends to be icky about ids. Not that I have a better one

Comment: @SomeshMukherjee i will suggest to create your own unique Id

Comment: I meant using foreign keys instead of relationships. tagID would be a foreign key here. I can't think of any way to represent this